# Chef server/Puppet master installation on Windows operating system

Tags: chef-infra, puppet

As I read a lot of documentations and communities post and all are telling that we can't install Chef-server on Windows, but I have to do some crucial work on this type of architecture. I already tried it by Puppet but this facility is also not supported by Puppet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way that you'll be able to run either on Windows is by running a Linux Virtual Machine on it, then the Chef Server or Puppet Master inside the VM.

Comment: yeah I know it but I want to install in windows environment.

Comment: If you want my honest advice, go to whomever gave you such requirements and tell them that it's not possible.

You *might* be able to hack something up using Unix libraries on Windows (such as Cygwin), but *if* it works it will certainly be much more hassle than it's worth it. Basically, it's like throwing both your time and their money off the window. :)

P.S.: Sorry if I sounded offensive, I was really not sure if this was serious.